# Поиск ближайших координат в golang без mongodb

Tags: golang, геолокация

В файле данных хранится несколько городов, в каждом городе от 3 до 10 точек со своими координатами.

Для определения города по координатам пользователя используется [github.com/kellydunn/golang-geo](http://github.com/kellydunn/golang-geo). Исходя из определившегося города загружаем координаты точек для нужного города. Как можно среди них найти ближайшие к пользователю в Golang без использования mongodb?

Comment: Не очень понятно, кто вас так упорно заставляет пользоваться MongoDB. Вопрос к ней всё равно прямого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @D-side предвосхищая ссылки, типа http://icchan.github.io/2014/10/18/geospatial-querying-with-go-and-mongodb/ решил сразу же оговорить использование mongodb с ее геокодингом

Comment: Да не парьтесь, тут таких могут заминусовать такие, как я (которым довелось поработать над продуктами, в которые монгу затянули исключительно для геокодинга; видимо, не зная, что есть масса других решений). К тому же, golang-geo всё равно Монгу не поддерживает.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/cdipaolo/d3f8db3848278b49db68

Код получения расстояния
В своем случае, я с его помощью сортирую точки и отдаю несколько ближайших

```
// haversin(θ) function
func hsin(theta float64) float64 {
    return math.Pow(math.Sin(theta/2), 2)
}

// Distance function returns the distance (in meters) between two points of
//     a given longitude and latitude relatively accurately (using a spherical
//     approximation of the Earth) through the Haversin Distance Formula for
//     great arc distance on a sphere with accuracy for small distances
//
// point coordinates are supplied in degrees and converted into rad. in the func
//
// distance returned is METERS!!!!!!
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
func Distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 float64) float64 {
    // convert to radians
  // must cast radius as float to multiply later
    var la1, lo1, la2, lo2, r float64
    la1 = lat1 * math.Pi / 180
    lo1 = lon1 * math.Pi / 180
    la2 = lat2 * math.Pi / 180
    lo2 = lon2 * math.Pi / 180

    r = 6378100 // Earth radius in METERS

    // calculate
    h := hsin(la2-la1) + math.Cos(la1)*math.Cos(la2)*hsin(lo2-lo1)

    return 2 * r * math.Asin(math.Sqrt(h))
}
```